# Pair Andorid Studio with github, git error?

Tags: android, programming, github

I'm working on a project with my teammates but when i try to pair the project on my andorid studio fro github on VCS into checkout from version control, when i click on clone i get this error

**Clone failed** 
*Failed to start Git process*

someone can help me?

I just installed git but... [image]

May I have to reboot the system?

Comment: Have you installed Git? sudo apt-get install git

Comment: @Smile4ever just edited the main

Comment: Does the answer below work? If so, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executable is not specific

`Android Studio` can't find executable `git` file. It seems to be not installed

Please press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` to open the `terminal` and run this command:

```
git --version
```

It would tell you if `git` is installed properly

If not, run this command

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that in Android Studio choose 'File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart'

Hope it help